# Publish succeeds but Visual Studio says it failed

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js web app in Visual Studio 2019 that gets published to Azure.  It's a site that is seasonal and I just brought it up to make updates for this season.  I have not published since last April but have not changed anything either.  I just changed a few static pages and published and the publish output says it was successful but the main screen says "Publish failed on 1/17/2022 at 11:35 AM.  Check output for more details."  I go to view the app on the internet and my changes are indeed there so it appears the publish was successful as indicated in the output, but why is VS telling me it failed?  Is there a log file I can look at somewhere?  Below is the picture of the top of the publish screen where it shows the failure, followed by the Build Output and the Web Publish Activity (sitename changed to xxx).

[image: Publish fail image]
**Output**

```
Build started...
------ Build started: Project: XXX, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
------ Publish started: Project: XXX, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://xxx-webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=xxx-webapp ...
Adding ACLs for path (xxx-webapp)
Adding ACLs for path (xxx-webapp)
Publish Succeeded.
Web App was published successfully http://xxx-webapp.azurewebsites.net/
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Web Publish Activity**

```
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://xxx-webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=xxx-webapp ...
Adding ACLs for path (xxx-webapp)
Adding ACLs for path (xxx-webapp)
Publish Succeeded.
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this issue tends to have a wide range of possible solutions, One of the possible workarround is

1. In your solution directory, delete the .vs folder.
2. If your project directory contains a pubxml file, please delete it.
3. After that, restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when my 2FA token expires. I usually do:

- open a new publish profile window
- re-login with your saved credentials
- token should now be renewed silently and azure resources can be browsed
- cancel new profile creation

Now after successful build and publish your site URL should be opened